# How is color handled in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, colors, applescript, rgb

I'm trying to use AppleScript to change the background color of a Finder window and came across this code snippet, which seems to work... However, I'm not sure the logic of the color array...

```
tell the icon view options of the front Finder window
    set the background color to {52942, 54484, 31097}
end tell
```

What does the {52942, 54484, 31097} AppleScript magic refer to? It doesn't look like RGB to me... How would I get something specific like red (#ff0000 | 255, 0, 0) or, better yet, a neon cyan (#00f6ff | 0, 246, 255)?

Comment: When fiddling with the values, I receive this error: "Finder got an error: Can’t make {12242, 84282, 41097} into type RGB color."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are four different numeric representations of the RGB  color.

`Notation` -- `RGB triplet` (**red**)

**1-** Arithmetic -- (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

**2-** Percentage -- (100%, 0%, 0%)

**3-** Digital 8-bit per channel -- (255, 0, 0) or sometimes #FF0000 (hexadecimal)

**4-** Digital 16-bit per channel -- (65535, 0, 0)

The component values are often stored as integer numbers in the range 0 to 255, the range that a single 8-bit byte can offer. These are often represented as either decimal or hexadecimal numbers.

Multiply the integer (`standard RGB value`) by **257** to get the value in Digital 16-bit per channel (**AppleScript**)

Answer (score 2):

You don’t have to work with the colors as numbers. There is a choose color command that shows the system color picker.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    tell the icon view options of the front window
        set the background color to choose color
    end tell
end tell
```

… but for some reason, after running this script you will have to close and then reopen the Finder window to see the color change.